# Startup script for starting applications in certain workspaces and positions

Tags: 11.04, startup, scripts, workspaces

Since Ubuntu 11.04 has removed the session save feature, is it possible to write a script to open certain applications in specified workspaces and set their position? Please provide an example (for terminal, browser and etc.).

Answer (score 2):

There is [Devilspie](http://burtonini.com/blog/computers/devilspie/) which will do everything you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a script like

```
#!/bin/sh
firefox & disown
gnome-terminal & disown
```

and put that somewhere. Then go into Settings, there is some Startup Items menu. Just add your script and that should do.

Comment: what about workspace and positions?

Comment: no idea how to do that … maybe you can tell compiz or metacity where to put windows.